# R: error in mle initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Tags: r, statistics, mle

```
nll <- function(lambda, kappa){
  logit=function(x) {log(x/(1-x))}
  a=c(1-exp(-(15/lambda)^kappa), 1-exp(-(25/lambda)^kappa), 1-exp(-(35/lambda)^kappa))
  a=logit(a)
  mu = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
  mu = logit(mu)
  cov = matrix(c(0.18830690, 0.00235681, 0.00071954, 0.00235681, 0.00736811, 0.00110457, 0.00071954, 0.00110457, 0.00423955), nrow =3)
  L1 = dmvnorm(a, mu, cov)

  a=c(1-exp(-(25/lambda)^kappa), 1-exp(-(35/lambda)^kappa), 1-exp(-(45/lambda)^kappa))
  a=logit(a)
  mu = c(0.4, 0.1, 0.9)
  mu = logit(mu)
  cov = matrix(c(2.7595442, 0.0045178, 0.0010505, 0.0045178, 0.00972309, 0.0015120, 0.0010505, 0.0015120, 0.0088425), nrow =3)
  L2 = dmvnorm(a, mu, cov)
  -sum(log(L1*L2))
}


> mle(nll, start = list(lambda = 1, kappa = 1))
Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

I'm trying to find the lambda and kappa values that maximize the function above.

My original likelihood function returns `L1*L2`, but because the `mle` function requires the negative log-likelihood to be passed in, I modified the function to return `-sum(log(L1*L2))` instead.

However, I ran into the above error. And I've also tried specifying `dmvnorm(... ,log = TRUE)` but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: your variance-covariance matrices look fishy.  If they're all constant then they will be non-positive-definite (i.e. not legal variance-covariance matrices) and `dmvnorm` will return a non-finite value ...

Comment: @BenBolker I changed my covariance matrices. But the error still persists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `L1` and `L2` are both scalars. Assuming we're going to pass `log=TRUE` to `dmvnorm` so they are each log-likelihoods, do you mean just `-(L1+L2)` in the final line?
- by specifying `debug(nll)` and `nll(lambda=1,kappa=1)` , then stepping through the code, waiting til we find an infinite value, and then backtracking, we see that `1-exp(-(45/lambda)^kappa)` is exactly 1 (`exp(-45)` is less than 1e-16, the smallest value for which 1+x is > 1, so that the final element of `logit(a)` is infinite ...

So if I make `dmvnorm(...,log=TRUE)` in both places, change the last line to `return(-(L1+L2))`, and change the initial value of `lambda` to 10, I get a finite value for `nll(10,1)` (4474), and `stats4::mle(nll,start=list(lambda=10,kappa=1))` gives:

```
Coefficients:
   lambda     kappa 
40.622673  4.883857
```